# Update target of internal org-mode link

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I have a document full of internal org-mode links of the form:

```
* Target Heading

...

[[Target Heading][Description]]
```

However, these break whenever I edit the heading that they link to, so I want to replace them with links of the form:

```
* Target Heading
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       403847B2-3D4C-4EFB-96DE-E0C5C52A02B5
  :END:

...

[[#403847B2-3D4C-4EFB-96DE-E0C5C52A02B5][Description]]
```

I have started on some code that will follow the link at point, add an id to the heading it finds and save the link to that heading. I then want to update the link with the new target:

```
(defun adam-open ()
  (require 'org-id)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (call-interactively 'org-open-at-point)
       (call-interactively 'org-store-link)))
  (org-insert-link))
```

The trouble with this is that because the link under point already points to a text-based link, `org-insert-link` fails to replace the target with the stored id. Also, `org-insert-link` works interactively

Is there any way to pass the id as a parameter to `org-insert-link` so that it overrides the default text-based target and avoids the interactive prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `org-insert-link` not totally interactively with
 `(org-insert-link nil "other" "description")` but that won't help.

The following functions are a quick-and-dirty solution to update your org-links
 maintaining your descriptions and creating org-ids for headers, if needed.

```
(defun adl/org-link-update ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'org-id)
  (while (not (org-element-link-parser))
    (backward-char))
  (let ((list-of-links-p (org-element-property
          :contents-begin (org-element-link-parser))))
    (org-open-at-point)
    (cond ((org-at-heading-p)
       (org-id-get-create)
       (org-id-copy)
       (org-mark-ring-goto)
       ;;(org-insert-link)
       ;;(org-beginning-of-line)
       (insert "[[id:")
       (yank)
       (insert "]")
       (delete-forward-char 1)
       (when list-of-links-p
         (zap-to-char 1 ?\])))
      (t
       (org-mark-ring-goto)))))
```

`adl/org-link-update` affects org-link at point and `adl/org-link-update-buffer` affects all org-links in current buffer.

```
(defun adl/org-link-update-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (while (not (org-next-link))
    (when (string= "fuzzy"
           (org-element-property
            :type (org-element-link-parser)))
      (adl/org-link-update))))
```

**EDIT:** `adl/org-link-update-buffer` fixed.

https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html#orgae0b143 for reference.

**EDIT-2:** `adl/org-link-update` fixed.

To differentiate "single links" from "lists of links", I used the fact that `:contents-begin` property is `nil` for "single links" as `[[Heading 1]]` and it is not `nil` for "lists of links" as `[[Heading 1][Description]]`.

**EDIT-3:** `adl/org-link-update` fixed.

`adl/org-link-update` now affects only links targeting headings as @jagrg pointed out.

Comment: Thanks @adi! Can you think of how to limit this to internal org-mode links only?

Comment: sorry, I didn't consider other org-link types. I edited my answer.

Comment: Hi @adl - this is a good start! the script works fine for a simple list of links of the format [[Heading 1][Description]] where each link is on its own line. But if the link is used in a sentence or if it is formatted as [[Heading 1]] the script fails. It would be great if this could be made robust against these additional use cases!

Comment: Hi @Adam - I'm considering that you want to use only `adl/org-link-update-buffer`.

In this second edit, to `adl/org-link-update` works properly, you should place
 the cursor at the beginning of your org-link. Note that the beginning of a
 org-link is different from the beginning of displayed link text.

Comment: That did it. Thanksn @adl!

Comment: You're considering that all fuzzy links target one of the headings which is not always the case. Consider for example: <<targeta>> [[targeta]] or #+name: targetb [[targetb]]. I think you should leave those intact. Another problem is your solution fails if [[target]] is above the first headline.

Comment: @jagrg
Thanks for pointed out the fuzzy link generalization mistake, I fixed it.

My solution does work with [[target]] above linked headline.
In buffers where `(buffer-file-name)` is `nil`, `*scratch*` is an example,
 `org-open-at-point` fails to find entries with ids declared below the link,
 that is an `org-mode` issue.

Comment: @Adam
You are welcome.
I updated `adl/org-link-update` to affect only links targeting headings as @jagrg pointed out
and to fix the cursor position limitation created in last edit.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @adl

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to create `(title . ID)` element for each fuzzy link found in the buffer, and then replace the link with one that uses the heading's ID.

```
(defun adam-open ()
  (interactive)
  (let (headings alist)
    (save-excursion
      (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'link
    (lambda (link)
      (when (string= (org-element-property :type link) "fuzzy")
            (push (org-element-property :path link) headings))))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (outline-next-heading)
    (let* ((elt (org-element-at-point))
               (title (org-element-property :title elt)))
      (when (member title headings)
            (org-id-get-create))))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (outline-next-heading)
    (let* ((elt (org-element-at-point))
               (title (org-element-property :title elt))
               (id (org-element-property :ID elt)))
      (when (member title headings)
            (push (cons title id) alist))))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (not (org-next-link))
    (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'link
      (lambda (link)
            (let ((type (org-element-property :type link)))
              (when (and (string= type "fuzzy")
             (looking-at "\\[\\[\\([^]]*\\)\\(]]\\|]\\[[^]]*]]\\)"))
        (let* ((desc (match-string-no-properties 1))
               (id (assoc-default desc alist)))
          (when (member desc (mapcar #'car alist))
            (replace-match (format "[[id:%s][%s]]" id desc))))))))))))
```